# Can you have multiple name server set in registrar?

Tags: dns, registrar

Take for example I have bought my domain example.com at Namecheap.

I than set a custom customer name server in Namecheap because I am using Cloudflare as my authoritative DNS as follows

```
alpha.ns.cloudflare.com
beta.ns.cloudflare.com
```

Now my plan is to have DNS high-availability to prevent any DNS outage and ensure the accessibly my web application. I am going use another set of name server from Godaddy namely

```
ns01.domaincontrol.com 
ns02.domaincontrol.com
```

So can I add these 4 name server record from 2 DNS provider in Namecheap to achieve high-availability ?

```
alpha.ns.cloudflare.com
beta.ns.cloudflare.com
ns01.domaincontrol.com
ns02.domaincontrol.com
```

what I have tried is I added these records but in Godaddy it is still showing "This domain is registered elsewhere. To use these DNS records on your domain, set your domain to these nameservers at your registrar:" , only in Cloudflare is active.

Comment: Perhaps Godaddy is just not good in detecting your Namecheap setting because there is Cloudflare NS "above" it. Try http://dns.squish.net/, it should show if anything is wrong.

Comment: in theory my configuration is correctly ?

Comment: It might be, we can't tell unless you share your real domain name

Comment: Maybe if you provide output of `dig example.com ns +trace +short` (and remove your domain name but leave other data)